# ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo de otra manera para usar 'replace'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, str-replace

Estoy buscando la forma de convertir esta lista con el alfabeto a otra lista con números según las letras que contenga la lista, algo así:

```
alfabeto = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']

alfabeto_posiciones = []

for numeros in range(len(alfabeto)):

    alfabeto_posiciones.append([numeros])

[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]

numero = 4

alfabeto_posiciones = [posicion.replace(numero, alfabeto[numero]) for posicion in alfabeto_posiciones]

[0] [1] [2] [3] "f" [5]
```

El problema es que en la lista de alfabeto_posiciones que contiene los numeros no puedo usar replace ya que es una lista... lo mismo pasaria si saco sus '[]' y dejo solo los numeros ya que 'int' no tiene atributos para usar replace.

¿Hay alguna forma de usar solo la lista 'alfabeto' para obtener los números e ir desenmascarándolos en la misma lista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas pasándolo como un string y al ir dándole el valor de número le pasas como str() y concatenado cada número si te deja utilizar el replace()

```
alfabeto = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g']

alfabeto_posiciones = ''

for numeros in range(len(alfabeto)):    

alfabeto_posiciones+=str(numeros)

print(alfabeto_posiciones)
numero = 4

alfabeto_posiciones = [posicion.replace(str(numero), alfabeto[numero]) for posicion in alfabeto_posiciones]
print(alfabeto_posiciones)
```